# Is XGBoost4j-Flink compatible with multi-node parallelism?

Tags: apache-flink, xgboost

I'm trying to train an XGBoost model using the XGBoost4j-Flink package.
With flink parallelism setted to 1 it works, but **with parallelism > 1 it always throws this error**:

```
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostError: [11:13:50] /xgboost/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:64: Check failed: info.labels_.Size() != 0U (0 vs. 0) : label set cannot be empty
Stack trace:
   [bt] (0) /tmp/libxgboost4j2929418756774401857.so(dmlc::LogMessageFatal::~LogMessageFatal()+0x22) [0x7f91471def82]
   [bt] (1) /tmp/libxgboost4j2929418756774401857.so(xgboost::obj::RegLossObj<xgboost::obj::LogisticClassification>::GetGradient(xgboost::HostDeviceVector<float> const&, xgboost::MetaInfo const&, int, xgboost::HostDeviceVector<xgboost::detail::GradientPairInternal<float> >*)+0xec) [0x7f91472e8b6c]
   [bt] (2) /tmp/libxgboost4j2929418756774401857.so(xgboost::LearnerImpl::UpdateOneIter(int, xgboost::DMatrix*)+0x43b) [0x7f9147273dfb]
   [bt] (3) /tmp/libxgboost4j2929418756774401857.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x35) [0x7f91471e5845]
   [bt] (4) [0x7f91a9018407]

ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoostJNI.checkCall(XGBoostJNI.java:48)
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.Booster.update(Booster.java:181)
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.java.XGBoost.train(XGBoost.java:190)
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.XGBoost$.train(XGBoost.scala:64)
ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.flink.XGBoost$MapFunction.mapPartition(XGBoost.scala:60)
org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.MapPartitionDriver.run(MapPartitionDriver.java:99)
org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.run(BatchTask.java:503)
org.apache.flink.runtime.operators.BatchTask.invoke(BatchTask.java:368)
org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:711)
```

I used the following hyperparameters on every tests:

```
Subsample=1
Eta=0.05
Colsampletree=0.6
Silent=0
Objective=binary:logistic
Evalmetric=auc
Seed=42
Maxdepth=5
Minchildweight=6
Alpha=1.5
Booster=gbtree
Basescore=0.05
Nthread=8
Scaleposweight=0.5
Maxdeltastep=5
Gamma=0.1
Rounds=40
```

Is it possible that the implemented mapPartition performs an unwanted distribution leading to a node/worker processing a "one class dataset" ?

Also, I encountered some parameters as *num_workers* and *timeout_request_workers*, but it is not on the xgboost parameters documentation and specific to xgboost4j-spark. Is there some non documented parameters I have to use to run multi-node Flink XGBoost ?

Hopefully someone can help me out! Thanks.

Comment: How many task managers did you have, and with how many slots each?

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried different things. 1 TaskManager with 1 or more slots goes well, but it does not work for other configs (i.e. more than 1 TaskManager, even with 1 slot each)

Comment: I'm pretty sure XGBoost isn't thread-safe, but I was expecting that multiple TMs with 1 slot each would work. You can achieve even greater isolation by putting the operator(s) using XGBoost into their own slot-sharing group(s).

Comment: @DavidAnderson Thanks for the workaround, I will try smthg like that.